# start activity from Back-Stack without call method on create in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Activity A Call Activity B And B Call C i want to return to A ,Activity A is in BackStack how to return it without calling method onCreate  in Activity

Answer (score 0):

By using this code onCreate method will not call

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score -1):

> How about call the finish() of Activity B when you call the Activity C.

Comment: This is not a solution please write valid answer